# AsyncResult.successful() returns false, get() raises attribute error

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am trying to use Python's ThreadPool in the multiprocessing module for the first time to try and speed up some very slow log parsing.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be working properly. And I cannot find anyone with a similar case just by googling. I call `pool.join()` to wait for threads to finish and then iterate over them to access their return values. However, I find that whilst AsyncResult.ready() returns true, AsyncResult.successful() returns false. and When I call get() an attribute error is raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luke.timothy\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Monitor\monitor.py", line 175, in <module>
    stamp = threads[i].get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: _strptime
```

I also find that only 4 threads have completed by the time the `join()` function returns. This was unexpected as from the documentation I thought that join waited for all pool items to complete before returning. I also found that if I call `AsyncResult.wait()` on each thread before accessing the return value then nothing happens. It doesn't wait at all.

Here is the code:

```
def parse(all_logs):
    current_time_local = datetime.now()
    print "Parsing."
    stamps = []
    for line in all_logs:
        match = re.match(match_string, line)
        if match:
            for i in range(4):
                if match.group(1 + (i * 3)):
                    wheren = match.group(1 + (i * 3)).rstrip().strip("[").strip("]").split(",")
                    break

            stamp = datetime.strptime(wheren[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            if stamp.day == current_time_local.day or (stamp.day  == current_time_local.day-1 and stamp.hour >= current_time_local.hour):
                try:
                    name, aliases, ipaddrlist = socket.gethostbyaddr(wheren[1].split(":")[1])
                except:
                    continue
                stamps.append(Event(stamp,name,match.groups()))
    print "Returning stamps."
    return stamps

pool = ThreadPool(processes=8)

threads = []

for i in range(8):
    range_begin = i * logs_fraction
    range_end = range_begin + logs_fraction
    print "begin: " + str(range_begin) + " end: " + str(range_end)
    thread_args = []
    thread_args.extend(all_logs[range_begin:range_end])
    threads.append(pool.apply_async(parse, (thread_args, )))

pool.close()

pool.join()

for i in range(8):
    print "Getting thread " + str(i+1)
    print threads[i].ready()
    print threads[i].successful()
    print "Thread Ready."
    stamp = threads[i].get()
    print stamp
    stamps.extend(stamp)
```

Can anybody help? I have never used this module before and as far as my google searches have shown, material for learning it is rather sparse. The official Python documentation can only get me so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hitting a thread-safety issue in the datetime library, according to [this link](http://code-trick.com/python-bug-attribute-error-_strptime/).

> Last Friday, I met a Python Bug, so this weekend I spent some time to
>   investigate this bug and wrote this post to explain the root cause.
>   I’m not a Python specialist, a C programmer, instead. If you found
>   anything error please correct me.
>
> I extracted the minimize POC here:
>
> ```py
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import thread
> import time
>
> def thread_fn():
>     for _ in xrange(1, 10):
>         for _ in xrange(1, 100):
>             time.strptime("2013-06-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
>
> for _ in xrange(10):
>     thread.start_new_thread(thread_fn, ())
>
> time.sleep(1)
> ```
>
> Upper codes sometimes will throw out the exception: `AttributeError:
>   _strptime_time`, you can run it in your environment and check the output.
>
> I checked Python-2.7.2(Mac Default) and Python-2.7.3(Compiled from the
>   source code). I got this error randomly, which means sometimes this
>   script works fine!

And the workaround:

> You should realized this will be a multithread issue, right? Here is
>   the implementation of `time_strptime`,
>
> ```c
> static PyObject *
> time_strptime(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
> {
>     PyObject *strptime_module = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("_strptime");
>     PyObject *strptime_result;
>
>     if (!strptime_module)
>         return NULL;
>     strptime_result = PyObject_CallMethod(strptime_module,
>                                             "_strptime_time", "O", args);
>     Py_DECREF(strptime_module);
>     return strptime_result;
> }
> ```
>
> Each time when this function is called, it will try to load the module
>   “_strptime”. The algorithm of the API PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock is
>   if there’s a thread is importing that module, it will throw out the
>   exception instead of blocking there. This avoids the duplicate module
>   importing and potential deadlock.
>
> But in a multithreaded environment, when one thread is trying to import
>   _strptime, but has not been fully imported, another threads tried to call `strptime_module._strptime_time` directly. This is why the bug
>   happened.
>
> **If you understand well why this bug happened, you should already have
>   the workaround in your heart. Actually it’s really straightforward.
>   All you need to do just is call once `strptime` before starting your
>   threads.**

So it seems you can work around it by importing `_strptime` directly prior to creating threads.

[Here's the official bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue7980), which has more info.